# How to get two player records from same player table in one row in a table visualisation?

Tags: powerbi

I have a database table of sports matches which has two fields for player IDs: `p1_id` and `p2_id`. These fields both have foreign keys to a `player` table where there is an `id` and a `name` field.

I want to build a table visualisation in PowerBI that has both player names in a single row. I can't do this easily because I can only use one of the foreign key relationships at any one time. I've tried using `USERELATIONSHIP` but it looks like this can only be used within a `CALCULATE` function.

I'm sure there's a way to do this but it's beyond me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with lookupvalue.

```
p1Name = LOOKUPVALUE(players[Name],players[pID], SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[p1]))

p2Name = LOOKUPVALUE(players[Name],players[pID], SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[p2]))
```

[image]

You can also check this video [Lookup multiple values in DAX]:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRnIH0pnF3o&ab_channel=SQLBI

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to PowerBI - I've tried creating a column using `p1_name = LOOKUPVALUE('belgarath player'[name_], 'belgarath player'[id_], SELECTEDVALUE('belgarath match_overall'[p1_id]))` but it's completely blank...?

Comment: Do you create measures or CalculatedColumn?

Comment: I click on the `New column` button

Comment: If you don't need player Name as a group by column, then use measures.

Comment: Tried adding a measure as follows: `p1_name_m = LOOKUPVALUE('belgarath player'[name_], 'belgarath player'[id_], SELECTEDVALUE('belgarath match_overall'[p1_id]))`. Had a spinning wheel for over 10 mins which doesn't look good!